# Can we iteratively reflect on self elementary embeddable stages of the cumulative hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, embeddings

> Is it possible to iterate elementary embeddability and reflect on those stages that are elementary embeddable to themselves?

The following is a formal capture of that idea:

To the language of $\sf ZF$ (i.e., mono-sorted $\sf FOL(=,\in)$) add primitive partial unary functions $W$ and $j$.

To the axioms of $\sf ZF$, add the following axioms:

**Restriction:** $\forall  \alpha: W_\alpha \lor j_\alpha \to \operatorname {ordinal}(\alpha)$

**Injectivity:** $W_\alpha \land W_\beta \land \alpha \neq \beta \to W_\alpha \neq W_\beta$

**Cumulation:** $\forall \operatorname {ordinal} \alpha \exists \lambda: W_\alpha=V_\lambda$

**Elementarity:** $\forall \operatorname {ordinal} \alpha \, (j_\alpha: W_\alpha \to W_\alpha  \land \\ \forall \vec{x} \in W_\alpha [ \phi(\vec x) \leftrightarrow \phi(j_\alpha[\vec x ])] \land \\ \exists x: j_\alpha (x) \neq x) \\\text {where }   \phi \text { is purely set theoretic }$

**Reflection:** $\forall \vec{x} \in W_\alpha \, (\phi \to  \phi^{W_\alpha})$

if $\phi$ [in Reflection] is a formula of the language of set theory + $``j_\alpha \!"$, meaning that $W$ doesn't occur in it and every occurence of $j$ must be subscripted with $\alpha$; also $``\alpha \!"$ only appears in $\phi$ as a subscript of $j$.

Where $V_\lambda$ stands for the $\lambda^{th}$ stage of the cumulative hierarchy, defined in the customary manner. $\phi^X$ stands for relativising all quantifiers in $\phi$ to $``\in X\!"$.

> Is the above theory consistent relative to some large cardinal property? If so, Which one?

Comment: I believe several people already pointed it out, but the fact that your notation is non-standard undermines the understandability of your question. You said that $W_\alpha$ is a partial function, then what is the meaning of $W_\alpha$ as a prime formula? (Do you mean $\alpha$ is in a domain of $W$?)

Comment: Also, is there any restriction on $\phi$ in your formulation of Elementarity and Reflection? Formulation of the Elementarity of a Reinhardt embedding usually only considers formulas in which $j$ does not appear.

Comment: @HanulJeon, yes it means $\alpha$ is in the domain of $W$, it actually means $W(\alpha)$ but I don't like writing it this way. $\phi$ in elementarity axiom does't use $j$. In Reflection axiom, it can use it.

Comment: You may not like using $W(\alpha)$ instead of $W_\alpha$, yes, that is okay, but could you write "$W_\alpha$ is well-defined" instead of just putting $W_\alpha$ alone?

Comment: @HanulJeon, I don't think this is a big issue, it is well known approach, you always use it with the $V_\alpha$ stages, the $H_\alpha$ stages, etc.., it is obvious what I'm using. Of course it is well defined symbol.

Comment: It was most definitely not obvious to me what you meant with that. Anyway, doesn't cumulation axiom imply that $W_\alpha$ exists for all $\alpha$? Or is it only meant to apply for $\alpha$ for which $W_\alpha$ is well defined?

Comment: @Wojowu, what? I don't understand your question? Of course it means that $W_\alpha$ exists for all $\alpha$.

Comment: If it's defined for all $\alpha$, then what's the point of specifying it is a partial unary function, and then dabbling with $W_\alpha$ meaning it exists for a given $\alpha$? Also, if we are to be overly pedantic like you are trying to be, this also contradicts the first axiom saying it being well-defined implies $\alpha$ is an ordinal.

Comment: @Wojowu,Ah! Now I understand what you are speaking about. Yes! you are right. I meant for every ordinal $\alpha$, I've made the correction. Thanks.

Comment: Zuhair, your edit to your question has change it immensely, I'll add an answer for the edited question but for the future if you have "small edits" like those, ask in the comment of the existing answer and see if the OP of the answer will have an answer or it deserves a different question, you should avoid editing questions as much as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\Ord{\mathit{Ord}}$The edit to the question has changed it enough so I think it deserves its own answer.

I assume that in reflection we have $\forall \vec{x} \in W_\alpha \, (\phi \to  \phi^{W_\alpha})$ holds for all ordinals $\alpha$.

The theory with this strong reflection is inconsistent in a strong sense.

Specifically it fails even when you only consider $W_0$.

Indeed assume that $W_0$ reflects all formulae in the language of $\{\in,j_0\}$ then it reflects $\eta=\exists x(x\notin \operatorname{Dom}(j_0))$, so let $p\in W_0$ be witness of $\eta^{W_0}$.

$W_0$ also reflects $\psi(y)=\exists x\in \Ord (y\in V_x)$, let $r$ be witness of $\psi(p)$ in $W_0$.

Lastly reflect $\phi(y)=y\in \Ord\land V_y\subseteq \operatorname{Dom}(j_0)$ to get that $W_0$ thinks that $\phi(r)$, but this is a contradiction to the choice of $r$, $p$ (note that I only chose 1 arbitrary element, $p$, so I didn't use any choice).

Comment: Are you using absolutness of "..is an ordinal" over transitive models of ZF in the last step, because $r$ is seen by $W_0$ as ordinal, it need not be so externally unless you are using some kind of absolutness of ordinality over $W_0$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I am using the fact that "being an ordinal" is absolute between transitive models, you don't need them to be models of ZF ("$x$ is an ordinal" is $\Delta_0$), but yes, I did use that fact. With a bit more effort you can show that even if we don't assume $W_0$ is transitive your strong reflection principle implies "being is ordinal" is absolute between $V$ and $W_0$

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 6):

Any model of $ZF$+stationary proper class of $I3$ ordinals (whose consistency strength is at most $ZF$+$I2$) where $W_α$ is listing of $V_{κ}$ where $κ$ is $I3$ and $j_α$ the witness of $I3(V_κ)$ will be a model of your theory.

Injectivity and Cumulation are trivial, $ZF$+Elementarity is part of our assumption.

For Reflection, let $φ$ be any formula, by Levy's reflection principle there is a proper class club $C_φ$ that reflect $φ$ (note that Levy's reflection works even with a modified language).

Because there is a stationary set of $I3$ cardinals, there exists a $I3$ cardinal in $C_φ$, then this ordinal will witness Reflection of $φ$.

---

This section is a follow-up based on the comments.

Let $\cal L$ be the language of our theory (or any other language extending $\{∈\}$), and let $ZF_{
\cal L}$ be $ZF$ with schema over the language $\cal L$ then *any model of $ZF$ is (under a suitable interpretations) a model of $ZF_{
\cal L}$*.

The reason for this is that we do not have any axioms to restrict
any of our new symbols, let interpret each relation symbol in $\cal L\setminus\{∈\}$ as a tautology, each function symbol as the identity, and each constant as the emptyset.

Because all 3 of those are definable, any formula containing any symbols in $\cal L$ will be equivalent to a formula in $\{∈\}$.

So $\forall \alpha \,( W_\alpha \models \sf ZF_{\cal L})$ doesn't imply $W_\alpha$ is a model of ZF+Reinhardt, because while it does satisfy schema over the symbol $j$ and $W$, it does not see any nee from the universe to itself (The symbol of $j$ in $W_α$ **has no relation** to the symbol $j$ in $V$)

Now what about the reflection principle? In our language we have $2$ extra symbols, $j,W$.

We can restrict ourselves to $α$ such that $W_α$ reflects enough to prevent the triviality we had in the second paragraph of the follow-up, but it doesn't matter.

To show that it doesn't matter, look at the sentence $∀x(x∈Ord\implies ∃y∈Ord(\text{such that $W_x=V_y$ and $j_x$ is nee from $W_x$ to itself}))$, assume it is reflected into $W_α$, why is $W_α$ not Reinhardt? The reason is that $W_α$ does not see all of the ordinals, so while we may have $α∈W_α$ (well, for this specific sentence if it is reflected to $W_\alpha$ then $V_\alpha=W_\alpha$ so $\alpha\notin W_\alpha$, but this is irrelevant to my point), the value of $W_α^{W_α}$ is a **proper** subset of $W_α$, so $j,W$ inside of $W_α$ cannot say anything about the real $W_α,j_α$, i.e. we can not see any nee on $W_α$ inside of $W_α$.

So **how can we get Reinhardt**? To get Reinhardt we **must** adjust the nee $j_α$ to $W_α$, define for a set $X,Y$ the model $(X,∈,Y^{(k)})$ be the model $(X,∈,Y)$ but the symbol for $Y$ is $k$ and add the following axiom (remember that as long as we don't add interpretations/axioms on new symbols, they don't change the theory, so we can require just $ZF_{\{∈,k\}}$ instead of $ZF_{\{∈,k,j,W\}}$):

> For every ordinal $α$, $(W_{α},∈,j_{α}^{(k)})⊨ZF_{\{∈,k\}}$

This is exactly your theory with the extra axiom that "$W_α$ can see the nee on itself".

This theory is very strong, I *want to say* that this theory is equivalent to "ZF + there is stationary proper class of $α$ such that $V_α$ is a model of Reinhardt", but I am not 100% sure about the $⇒$ direction (the proof of $⇐$ direction is essentially the same as my original answer but replacing $I3$ with Reinhardt).

Comment: I thought this theory is stronger than Reinhardt cardinals

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar No, it is much weaker. The problem is that having a lot of elementary embedding doesn't give us a way to "stich them together" to get Reinhardt. And even if you had a way to stich them together there is no reason to believe that the "resulting stich" won't be the identity. (For example, it is consistent [relative to blah blah] that there is proper class of $I3$ ordinals, and for every ordinal $α$, there is some $β$ such that the elementary embedding for the $I3$ ordinals above $β$ are the identity on $V_α$, so the embeddings are "eventually the identity")

Comment: If one adds the axoim that $\forall \alpha \,( W_\alpha \models \sf ZF)$, then would that interpret $\sf  ZF + Reinhardt $ at each $W_\alpha$?

Comment: @Zuhair It depends on how to formulate $\mathsf{ZF}$. If we do not allow Separation and Replacement for formulas with $j$, then Holo's answer still works even if you assume $W_\alpha$ models $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: @HanulJeon, There is no restriction here on formulas used in Separation and replacement, so of course they can use $j$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar ZFC + I3 at $\alpha$ implies $V_\alpha\models$ ZFC, but $(V_\alpha,j)\not\models$ ZFC$_j$ where $j:V_\alpha\to V_\alpha$ witnesses I3 at $\alpha$.

Comment: @HanulJeon it does not matter how to formulate it, to get Reinhardt you need "ZF+(schemas including j)+**j is elementary embedding**", just adding symbols without any restriction on the symbols doesn't change anything (let $L=FOST + F + R + C$ where $F$ are set of new function symbols, $R$-set of relations symbols, $C$ set of new constants, interpret every new symbol as $∅$, and any model of ZF will be a model of ZF with the new language with schemas allowing the new symbols)

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar as FarmerS said, just requiring it being a model of $ZF$ doesn't add any power, you need to require something on how it interpret $j_α$ to change anything

Comment: Holo, I do not understand the point of your comment. What I pointed out was that Zuhair's theory is interpreted in your setup even if we additionally assume $W_\alpha$ models $\mathsf{ZF}$ over Zuhair's theory. If we require each $W_\alpha$ to satisfy $\mathsf{ZF}_j$ and $j$ is an elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$ itself, then the existence of $W_\alpha$ would demonstrate there is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ with a Reinhardt cardinal.

Comment: @HanulJeon Requiring $\forall \alpha \,( W_\alpha \models \sf ZF)$ with the new language does not makes each $W_α$ satisfy $ZF+j_α\text{ is elementary embedding}$, $W_α$ may interpret $j_α$ different from how $V$ interpret it

Comment: This is the reason why I stated "Separation and Replacement for formulas with $j$" (and in this case, schemas with $j_\alpha$ over $W_\alpha$.)

Comment: @HanulJeon "separation and replacement for formulas with $j_α$" *still* doesn't mean $W_α$ will interpret $j_α$ as elementary embedding, I don't understand how separation and replacement for $j_α$ will do anything without any extra (non-ZF related) axioms

Comment: I supposedly assume it is an elementary embedding over $W_\alpha$. It is my fault that I did not list every axiom I should state to avoid your confusion.

Comment: @HanulJeon no worries, with the additional context your comment is on point

Comment: @Holo, But $j_\alpha$ is an elementary embedding from $W_\alpha$ to $W_\alpha$ and $W_\alpha \models \sf ZF$, so it is an elementary embedding from a universe of disoucrse of ZF to itself, so how can there be no Reinhardt cardinal in $W_\alpha$? $j_\alpha$ is not trivial, so it must have a critical point, why that isn't a Reinhardt's cardinal?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar If you want $(W_α,∈,j_α)$ to be a model of $ZF+Reinhardt$ you need $j_{α}^{(W_α,∈,j_α)}$ to be elementary embedding, there is no reason to believe that $j_α^{(W_α,∈,j_α)}$ have anything related to $j_α^V$. To maybe better understand this, try to think about $j_{2^{2^{2^{|α|}}}}^{(W_α,∈,j_α)}$, it can't be $j_{2^{2^{2^{|α|}}}}$ because $j_{2^{2^{2^{|α|}}}}$ is a function between $W_{2^{2^{2^{|α|}}}}$ to itself, but $W_α$ doesn't see anything close to $W_{2^{2^{2^{|α|}}}}$

Comment: @Holo, but that can be seen in $W_{\alpha+1}$ about $W_\alpha$, or is it the case that I must allow $W_\lambda, j_\lambda$ symbols to be used in Elementarity axiom forall $\lambda < \alpha$, for that to be seen in it.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar $W_{α+1}$ can see that the $κ$ such that $W_α=V_κ$ is $I3$, but for it to be Reinhardt you need to have that $W_α$ internally see the replacement of $j_{α}$

Comment: @Holo, I'm sure you are right, I can feel it, but I can't fathom it. Replacement using $j_\alpha$ of course hold in the $W_\alpha$ world, there is no restriction on it. The critical point of $j_\alpha$ is ought to be a Reinhardt cardinal, there is something I'm missing.

Comment: @Holo, I think the problem was in the last axiom, which I've coined it to allow the use of $j_\alpha$ in the formula of reflection but I made the wrong restriction. I've corrected it. Perhaps, this corrects matters.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar it still doesn't work, and actually the reflection scheme doesn't even make sense, if you are intending the $\phi$ in the reflection scheme to be in the language with symbol $j$, since you write "$W_\alpha\models\phi$", but $W_\alpha=V_\lambda$ for some $\lambda$, which doesn't have any interpretation for $j$.

Comment: @FarmerS, I don't get your objection. It's unlcear.

Comment: In the reflection scheme, what language is the formula $\phi$ in?

Comment: @FarmerS, the language of set theory + $j_\alpha$.

Comment: $j_\alpha$ is not a symbol; it's a function in the model, no?

Comment: Do you mean that the language is set theory + j, and you want to interpret j with $j_\alpha$?

Comment: I mean every occurrence of $j$ in the formula must be followed by $\alpha$ as subscript

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I will edit soon today (or tomorrow morning) to write a fully detailed explanation about all of the discussion in the comments inside of the post, and I hope it will clear things up

Comment: You seem to be blurring the distinction between symbols and their interpretations. Okay, let's do that (you also do that at the outset by adding the "partial functions W,j to the language ZF"). But $\phi$ must be in  (a subset of) the language of the original structure (because it appears as the hypothesis in the reflection scheme formula)...

Comment: But then the following formula $\phi$ is true: "For every $\alpha\in\mathrm{dom}(j)$, $j(\alpha)$ is a function". So by the reflection scheme, we can find some $\alpha$ such that $\phi^{W_\alpha}$ holds. You also say that there is $\lambda$ such that $W_\alpha=V_\lambda$. So $\phi^{V_\lambda}$ holds. But $V_\lambda$ has no interpretation for the symbol $j$. I suppose what you really meant to say was that $\phi^{(W_\alpha,j_\alpha)}$ holds. Well, then $(W_\alpha,j_\alpha)\models$"For every $\beta\in\mathrm{dom}(j_\alpha)$, $j_\alpha(\beta)$ is a function"...

Comment: But that's not true, because $\mathrm{dom}(j_\alpha)=W_\alpha$ and $j_\alpha$ is elementary, so if we let $x\in W_\alpha$ be a non-function, then $j_\alpha(x)$ is not a function. So the theory is inconsistent.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: @Holo, ,Farmer sorry for the delay, but I'll need some time to read it and return back to you.

Comment: @FarmerS, your formula $\phi$  doesn't meet the specifications I've given for the use of $j $ in it (I've updated the question with those specifications), also you are double quantifying over $\alpha$ in a nested manner, which makes the axiom using it a non well formed formula.